# richtextbox is shrinking at run time however textbox is not

Tags: c#

i'm at a loss as to why my parameter richtextbox is resizing its height at runtime. I'm assuming that it has something to do with my high def displays.

all other fields are simply textbox.

any suggestions as to fields I can check? Form.AutoScale is set to font.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uthG2.jpg

[image: design view and runtime view]

Comment: Did you try to check the `Minimum` height property of the `Textbox`? Did you set the `AutoSize` property of the `Textbox` to `true`?

Comment: WinForms, WPF, a reproducable MCVE? Please edit your question. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue is directly related to the use of the font "Microsoft YaHei". Changing the font to San Serif immediately resolved the issue.